# $V(x,xy)=V(x)$ but also $V(x,xy)=V(xy)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intuition

In $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]$, we have
$$V(x,xy)=V(x)$$
but if we expand the LHS we also get
\begin{align}
V(x,xy)&=V(x) \cap V(xy)\\
&=V(x) \cap (V(x) \cup V(y))\\
&=(V(x) \cap V(x))\cup (V(x) \cap V(y))\\
&=V(x) \cup V(xy)\\
&=V(xy).
\end{align}

$V(x)$ corresponds to the $y$-axis, but $V(xy)$ corresponds to the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes.

What is going on here?

Comment: @the_candyman these are standard notions in algebraic geometry. $k$ is a field and $x, y$ are indeterminates making $k[x,y]$ a polynomial ring. $V$ is the vanishing set of an ideal and $\text{Spec}$ refers to the ring spectrum.

Comment: For teachers: nice trap to check if your students are asleep or following your lecture in awe and admiration, as required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your third and fourth lines aren't equal:  $V(xy) = V(x) \cup V(y)$, not $V(x) \cap V(y)$.  The latter consists of the origin.